# docker-compose down and up from within a container

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, docker-compose, tmux

I am trying to perform a **docker-compose down** and **up** from within a container (the one that this same docker-compose brings up).

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down && docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

If I would do this in the container itself (with `docker.sock` mounted), the **up** part would not succeed, because the container would be down, of course.

My best try so far was to connect to host via ssh `ssh user@localhost` and execute this in the background using tmux, screen or nohup, but none of that could bring the container up, only the down part works:

```
tmux new -d "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down && docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d"
```

So, if this command runs in the background, why doesn't it bring the containers back up? Or is there a better solution for this problem?

Comment: Are there specific containers you're trying to restart?  Has something changed in the environment that you're trying to restart them?

Comment: The reason I am doing this is because the container tag changed, so I am actually updating the container with newer version. There is only one container in the compose file.

Comment: Can you run the orchestrator somewhere else – a separate container, or directly on the host?  Is your final deployment environment single-host Compose?  (If you were planning to run in Kubernetes anyways, this workflow is a little more possible there.)

Comment: A separate container created from this one could be possible, but not preferable, so running docker-compose up and down from the host is the ideal option. It is a single-host environment. I am not so familiar with using Kubernetes at this moment, so is not viable, maybe in the future.